# Vendor pre-payments do not show up in bank reconciliation in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, finance, vendor

We've added vendor pre-payments to NetSuite.

However, they don't show up on the bank reconciliation page.

Did we miss something, do we need to be using a certain kind of account or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a show all transaction types checkbox in accountancy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Vendor Prepayment is supported in Match Bank Data.
Do check if your Vendor Prepayment status is approved i.e. Paid
and the bank account selected in the Match Bank Data page and date filter (if any) match the fields in the prepayment as well.

Comment: Somebody else solved this and forgot about this question. There is a show all transaction types checkbox in accountancy settings. Think I'll probably delete this question. Thanks though.